# I have had a great night with you

Tags: traducción

I'd like to know how to say:

> *I have had a great night with you*

in Spanish.

Comment: the kind of interlocutor will definitely help choosing the proper translation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an increasing degree of how good the night was, or how much you want to express it:

> 1. *La pasé bien contigo* (maybe it's not necessary to refer to "the night"), or *la pasé bien contigo anoche* (last night) or *la pasé bien contigo la otra noche* (if it wasn't yesterday)
> 2. *Pasé una muy buena noche contigo.*
> 3. *¡Ayer estuviste excelente!* (deviation from literal meaning, and a more sexual connotation)
> 4. *La noche que pasé contigo fue maravillosa,* (may be a little formal)

Comment: The last example would be also polite, for example if it's the first night you date a person and it's too soon to be informal.

Answer (score 1):

"I have had a great night with you" suggests that the night is still going on or that you're at the end of the night (maybe parting ways with your friend). If you mean that you had a great night last night or some other night in the past, then it should be "I had a great night with you" (note that "have" is removed).

Assuming you want the latter meaning, I'd say "lo pasé muy bien contigo anoche." Frequently "lo" is used instead of "la" (see Jorge Campos's answer) to refer to the events of the night, in general, and not the night itself. If you want the meaning expressed in your original sentence, then I'd say "lo he pasado muy bien contigo." This is more appropriate for the good-byes at the end of the night.